# What is the name of the control that combines the function of a button and a combobox?

Tags: .net, qt, combobox, button, controls

What is the name of the control that combines the function of a button and a combobox?  Visual Studio's open file dialog has this control for the "Open" button.  You can select "Open" or "Open With".  But once you select an action, the corresponding action is taken.

Lastly, is this control available as a standard control in .NET or in Qt?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've often seen it called a "SplitButton".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It too me a while, but I found the answer for Qt.  The standard QPushButton control can be used.  All one has to do is use **[the QPushButton::setMenu(...) method (link)](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/qtextended4.4/qpushbutton.html#setMenu)**.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a SplitButton and as far as I know, Windows Forms only includes one for toolbars. Don't know about Qt, though.

I have found [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/SplitButton.aspx), though. The style seems a little off<sup>1</sup> on Windows 7 but I think for most people it should be pretty convincing.

---

<sup>1</sup> No fade animation on mouse enter and leave, the drop-down arrow changes size when hovering. But at least the first one also holds true for the checkboxes in that form; and the textboxes don't get their usual blue frame when active.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can name it a "DropButton" (cause it has a dropdown list, with additional actions). No its not available in .NET (Qt i didn´t know).

You have to use a 3rd Party component or build your own.

[Krypton](http://www.componentfactory.com/) provides an implementation of such a button. And its free to use.

BTW i think you can build your own when you use a default button and add a contextmenu to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's also known as a `ComboButton`. Look [here for information](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-2-dijit/form-validation-specialized-input/buttons-dropdown-combo-checkbox-ra). If you are using WPF and are wanting to make one, look at [this](http://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=5&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeproject.com%2FKB%2FWPF%2FWpfSplitButton.aspx%3Fmsg%3D2960328&ei=VpioSvW-AojbjQfzs4TYBw&usg=AFQjCNFoAyHjsf8M8sGmBgFPz3Of3Pb3Sg&sig2=tAy4hCvzUuZm9tpqW6P8BA) and try to apply it in making the control.